# Install 'createrepo' package opensuse SLES 15 SP4

Tags: linux, installation, opensuse, sles, zypper

Hi I am having difficulty installing the 'createrepo' package on opensuse SLES 15 SP4. I've ran

```
zypper install createrepo
```

But I am missing the necessary repos and cannot find the correct repos for the OS I am using. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The package is named `createrepo_c` and can be found in repository `SLE-Module-Basesystem15-SP4-Pool`. There is also `python3-createrepo_c` in repository `SLE-Module-Desktop-Applications15-SP4-Pool`.